# How to simulate mouseenter event in Selenium or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, ui-automation, marko

I've been working on a web UI automation task with `Selenium`, `Javascript` and `SeLion`. I would like to take a screenshot of some equivalent scenario as Google homepage below:
[image]

In which the "Search by voice" should be present when mouse moves in that microphone icon (neither Click or Hover). I have search bunch of solutions, unfortunately non of them works as expected.

I'm basically dealing with something like this:

```
<div id="div_id">
  <button type="button" class="button_class" disabled="" data-marko=" . 
    {"onclick":"handleClick s0-2-0-27-0 
    false&quot;,"onkeydown":"handleKeydown s0-2-0-27-0 false"}" 
    title="This message shows by mouseenter event" aria-label="This 
    message shows by mouseenter event">
      <span class="span_class"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

When mouse enters that button, "`This message shows by mouseenter event`" will be present. The page is likely written by [Marko-js](https://github.com/marko-js/marko). Couldn't really handle it with plain Javascript, I tried.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a working exaple in JsFiddle or other platforms ?

Answer (score 0):

> In which the "Search by voice" should be present when mouse moves in that microphone icon (neither Click or Hover)

if u read this link : https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events , it says that only user agent events can trigger "search by voice" . its cant be done by scripts

Answer (score 0):

I provided you a simple **working** example, give me a feedback if it is suitable for your needs.

```js
function simulateMouseEnter() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseenter', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var myTarget = document.getElementById('target_div'); 
  var canceled = !myTarget.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}

function mouseEnterBehaviour() {
    myElement = document.getElementById("target_div");
     // attach mouseenter event listener to element
    myElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
        // change the color of the font
        event.target.style.color = "red";
    });  
    // call the simulation
    setTimeout(simulateMouseEnter,3000);
}

mouseEnterBehaviour();
```

```html
<div id="target_div">target div</div>
```

**Note:** this should work with the most of the browser events

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This code works perfectly but not in my scenario. I've added some details in my question, please take a look. Thanks